# How do I encrypt string in nodejs with public generated by java

Tags: java, node.js, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I want to encrypt my password in angular side before sending it to Springboot API. My idea is to do:-

1. Generate public key and private key in java
2. Do a base64 encoding on both public key and private key
3. Use encoded public key in node (angular) side, this will be used for encryption
4. Use encoded private key in springboot rest api, this will be used for decryption

Below is my java code which generates, encrypts and decrypts password

**RSAKeyPairGenerator.java**

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec;
import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec;
import java.util.Base64;

import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;

public class RSAKeyPairGenerator {
    private static String privateKeyString = "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";
    private static String publicKeyString = "MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQC8kdVkalQbr3Zl5oK3GeFTGOISBU2LetzRhDfWrZYJ54DZYjGrL8waH540bZOZrpHs1Cro7Tjepj5wIyiaBA3YmsN0ZNISr4FuTLM8lAROWy04XsVS24vp0GEn9hkr3dH43WZ+io4YFTnW2HviXblP4jw9/04uafsNzHsIGactkQIDAQAB";
    private static PrivateKey privateKey;
    private static PublicKey publicKey;
    
    public void generateKeys() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        keyGen.initialize(1024);
        KeyPair pair = keyGen.generateKeyPair();
        RSAKeyPairGenerator.privateKey = pair.getPrivate();
        RSAKeyPairGenerator.publicKey = pair.getPublic();
    }
    
    public void readKeys() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");

        byte [] encoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(privateKeyString);
        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpec1 = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(encoded);
        RSAKeyPairGenerator.privateKey = kf.generatePrivate(keySpec1);
        
        encoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(publicKeyString);
        X509EncodedKeySpec keySpec2 = new X509EncodedKeySpec(encoded);
        RSAKeyPairGenerator.publicKey = kf.generatePublic(keySpec2);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, InvalidKeySpecException {
        RSAKeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = new RSAKeyPairGenerator();
        // Next line is for testing with encrypted text generated by nodejs code with genrated keys
        // keyPairGenerator.generateKeys();
        keyPairGenerator.readKeys();
        
        System.out.println("-----Private----------");
        System.out.println(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(privateKey.getEncoded()));
        System.out.println("Encoding : "+ privateKey.getFormat());
        System.out.println("----------------------");
        
        System.out.println("-----Public----------");
        System.out.println(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(publicKey.getEncoded()));
        System.out.println("Encoding : "+ publicKey.getFormat());
        System.out.println("----------------------");
        
        String secretMessage = "Test";
        System.out.println(secretMessage);
        
        Cipher encryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        encryptCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
        
        byte[] secretMessageBytes = secretMessage.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        byte[] encryptedMessageBytes = encryptCipher.doFinal(secretMessageBytes);
        // Next lines are for testing decryption with encrypted text generated by nodejs code with generated keys
        // byte[] encryptedMessageBytes = "B��u���<⌂׷�lǚm0�W������1�%EN�7��‼��l��l�<�����k;�������GĦ9D8��Z��I�Oɺ♫��→P'�§�{k�Ɋ+-}?��rZ".getBytes();
        // byte[] encryptedMessageBytes =  Base64.getDecoder().decode("woboAUytDXJLlKm7zbqNdxVORG+kio9kZxvMPOHruQfxwNEx7SVFTsw3oeETqbRs4NZskjzO2Nzjyms73vv758Dcy0fEpjlEOKmrWuG62knOT8m6DqGDGlAn1hXpe2u6yYorLX0/6fhyWg1C/JR1sbaKPH/Xt+Fsx5ptMONX0uw=");
        System.out.println(new String(encryptedMessageBytes));
                
        Cipher decryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA1AndMGF1Padding");
        decryptCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
        
        byte[] decryptedMessageBytes = decryptCipher.doFinal(encryptedMessageBytes);
        String decryptedMessage = new String(decryptedMessageBytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        System.out.println(decryptedMessage);
    }
}
```

This gives me following output

```
-----Private----------
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
Encoding : PKCS#8
----------------------
-----Public----------
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDL/rfg+v+2WOpvgow/ezQffPT9mI5hnBNsh1KJMo5sVYv0sSLvTG6IlTXsEfphY0xWDxoDFh89f13lRpYp4zf+ftH3YjvyRLxFIpRZpJCBdzMtdSNPW/TWfUSZqQjQm6joOzUrelQ/CAv8NfTduccHKH3N6m4HxIykrNAoMX2oawIDAQAB
Encoding : X.509
----------------------
Test
�N::�`��\A���ƈ�~��5s���
�0�I�C�uƹx2�Z&Kں�"ьC�$
q��K���h�^<�5�E�Ɨ0B�͒Z�{��EDbDH�.��#:�e��h~j���������q�c��R�
Test
```

In the Nodejs side I am using the above public to encrypt my text.

**index.js**

```js
const crypto = require("crypto");

var pubkey = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nMIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDL/rfg+v+2WOpvgow/ezQffPT9mI5hnBNsh1KJMo5sVYv0sSLvTG6IlTXsEfphY0xWDxoDFh89f13lRpYp4zf+ftH3YjvyRLxFIpRZpJCBdzMtdSNPW/TWfUSZqQjQm6joOzUrelQ/CAv8NfTduccHKH3N6m4HxIykrNAoMX2oawIDAQAB\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";

var plaintext = "Test"
var buffer = new Buffer.from(plaintext, "utf8");
var enc = crypto.publicEncrypt(pubkey, buffer);
var bs64 = enc.toString('base64');

console.log(enc.toString());
console.log(enc.toString('base64'));
```

this gives me following output

```
B��u���<⌂׷�lǚm0�W������1�%EN�7��‼��l��l�<�����k;�������GĦ9D8��Z��I�Oɺ♫��→P'�§�{k�Ɋ+-}?��rZ
woboAUytDXJLlKm7zbqNdxVORG+kio9kZxvMPOHruQfxwNEx7SVFTsw3oeETqbRs4NZskjzO2Nzjyms73vv758Dcy0fEpjlEOKmrWuG62knOT8m6DqGDGlAn1hXpe2u6yYorLX0/6fhyWg1C/JR1sbaKPH/Xt+Fsx5ptMONX0uw=
```

Now I tried using both the strings in java side for decryption.

When I try decoding the string, it gives me following error

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Data must not be longer than 128 bytes
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.doFinal(RSACipher.java:346)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.engineDoFinal(RSACipher.java:391)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2168)
    at com.mindtree.starr.wsr.RSAKeyPairGenerator.main(RSAKeyPairGenerator.java:90)
```

And, when I try decoding the base64 string, it gie me following error

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Decryption error
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpadV15(RSAPadding.java:379)
    at sun.security.rsa.RSAPadding.unpad(RSAPadding.java:290)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.doFinal(RSACipher.java:365)
    at com.sun.crypto.provider.RSACipher.engineDoFinal(RSACipher.java:391)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2168)
    at com.mindtree.starr.wsr.RSAKeyPairGenerator.main(RSAKeyPairGenerator.java:90)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Turning arbitary bytes into a "string" only produces a corrupted version of the data, so don't waste your time with that. For the base64 stuff, I believe the problem is that the nodejs crypto defaults to OAEP padding. You'll need to explicitly specify OAEP padding on the Java side. You should **always** specify the full transformation string in `Cipher.getInstance()` anyways.

Comment: What is the correct transform string for OAEP padding? I used `Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA1AndMGF1Padding");` . It still give me same error. I have updated my java code for reference

Comment: The default padding of [`crypto.publicEncrypt()`](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#cryptopublicencryptkey-buffer) is OAEP with SHA1 for _both_ digests. This is applied in your NodeJS code. The counterpart in Java for the SunJCE provider is `RSA/ECB/OAEPPadding` or `RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA1AndMGF1Padding`. Alternatively you can pass the parameters explicitly with `OAEPParameterSpec`. Since you are using `RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA1AndMGF1Padding`, your code should work as it does online: https://www.jdoodle.com/iembed/v0/j32 with _hello world_ as decrypted data. If not, check code and provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was clearly described in the first comment and the solution is in second comment.

Correct transformation string for Cipher instance that worked for me is `RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-1AndMGF1Padding`

So below instantiation for decryption Cipher works perfectly.

```java
Cipher decryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-1AndMGF1Padding");
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try "RSA/None/OAEPWithSHA1AndMGF1Padding"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).